# Should URL must end with / or not inside URL class of Java?

Tags: java, sockets, httpurlconnection

I need to connect to the middleware server using 
java  URL and URLConnection classes .

When googled on to net , i found out some examples 
Where the url is ending with /
(http://www.oracle.com/)

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
```

And in some examples the url is without /

```
URL ur = new URL("http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.gif");
```

Could anybody please tell me , is that makes any difference , if so 
then how ca we choose a URL value ??

Comment: That middleware server should have some documentation about what URL to use to access its function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessary.

If the URL contain no path section (only has the domain name and its scheme), it may or may not contain **trailing slash**, i.e. `http://www.oracle.com/` or `http://www.oracle.com`. Both should be accessible. However, a normailzed URL of this must have traling slash.

[URL normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) is a convention that allows a URL to be written in a consistent manner. In the URL normalization, the trailing slash indicate that the URL is a directory not a file. For example:

```
 "http://www.oracle.com/" <- root path
 "http://www.oracle.com/pages/" <- "pages" is a directory
 "http://www.oracle.com/pages" <- "pages" is a file
 "http://www.oracle.com/myfile.gif" <- "myfile.gif" is a file
 "http://www.oracle.com/myfile.gif/" <- "myfile.gif" is a directory
```

However, this convention is only applied to a normalized URL and whether one should have a trailing slash or not depends entirely on the service implmentations.

Answer (score 1):

No, an URL does not have to end with `/`, but some URLs do.  Whether it does or not depends on which URL you are trying to access (normally you'd use the URL you have without modification).